# facebook graph api pagination not giving results for friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-friends, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am using graphi api to retrieve the name and id of my friends. In Graphy API Explorer, I use the query

`me/friends?fields=id,name`

It gives me 25 results on first page, with a next in paging section. When I try to get the next page. It returns me an empty page. Even though I have over 600 friends in my profile. It doesn't matter what offset and limit should i set it never gives the result apart from first 25 results.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to me that these 25 friends are the only ones that have used the app that generated your access token. For example if you are using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) it will only return the friends that have used that app.

I don't believe it's possible for any app to get a complete list of a user's friends due to the fact that not every friend as authorized that app to "see them" even public data.

[Click here for Source quoted bellow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)

> Permissions

- A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
- **This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.**
- If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

Comment: I am still bit confused about this part. I am actually trying to get my own friend list, and i have generated token and granted the app access. I didnt share the app with anyone of the 25 friends that I see in the results. Then how could it show the 25 people and not anymore.